# Mapping a wrapped collection to List

Tags: c#, automapper

It's pretty common for web APIs to wrap collections in an (unnamed) object, often with additional fields.

```
// GET http://api.example.com/foos/all
{
  "success": true,
  "count": 3,
  "foos": [
    { id: "foo1" },
    { id: "foo2" },
    { id: "foo3" }
  ]
}
```

In C# using Json.NET, that would map to something like this:

```
class FooData {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class FooDataWrapper {
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public FooData[] Foos { get; set; }
}

... 

var fooData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooDataWrapper>("{ ... }");
```

I don't want to pass `FooDataWrapper` around the rest of my code base so I usually create an entity class that contains just the foos stuff without the additional fields.

```
public class Foo { // entity model
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Can I now use AutoMapper to map an instance of `FooDataWrapper` to a list of `Foo`?

```
FooDataWrapper fooDataWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooDataWrapper>("{ ... }");
List<Foo> foos = Mapper.Map<FooDataWrapper, List<Foo>>(fooDataWrapper);
```

What would the `CreateMap` look like to make this work?

Please just ignore that `Foo` and `FooData` look the same in this example. The real world usually doesn't have DTO objects that look exactly like the entity objects.

Comment: `Foo` and `FooData` look basically the same. Why do you need both? If you get rid of `FooData` then you could use `fooDataWrapper.Foos`.

Comment: Because this is a simplified example. My real `Foo` classes have many properties, often with different names or types than the `FooData` classes.

Comment: Would it be possible for to change the example slightly, so that they don't have the same properties?

Comment: This doesnt help? http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Comment: @kuskmen I don't think so, it looks like that doesn't deal with collections.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really easy to do once you know how.

You need to create two maps:

1. One regular map for mapping `FooData` to `Foo`
2. One helper map for mapping `FooDataWrapper` to `List<Foo>`

For the helper map you have to use a custom type converter because you can't use `ForMember` to select the entire destination object.

The custom type converter can be a lambda and just does `Mapper.Map(FooData[], List<Foo>)`.

```
// classic mapping
CreateMap<FooData, Foo>();

// helper mapping
CreateMap<FooDataWrapper, List<Foo>>()
  .ConvertUsing((wrapper, list, context) => context.Mapper.Map(wrapper.Foos, list, context));
```

You can even get fancy and use other properties from the wrapper object inside the type converter. Here's an example of how you would use the wrapper's `Count` property to set the initial capacity of the result list.

```
CreateMap<FooDataWrapper, List<Foo>>()
  .ConvertUsing((wrapper, list, context) => {
      var destination = list ?? new List<Foo>(capacity: wrapper.Count);
      return context.Mapper.Map(wrapper.Foos, destination, context);
  });
```